# Add gaussian noise to 2D Point

Tags: matrix, coordinate-transformation, random-process

I implemented a program for a camera calibration in Mathematica with with prototypical data to see if my calibration works. Here I converted 3D object coordinates into 2D sensor coordinates. I have chessboard with 20 points.
My cameracalibration works and i can reproject the sensor points in object points. Now I want to disturb the sensor coordinates with gaussian noise to see how my programm wokrs with typically sensor noise. But I don't now how to implement it.
So heres a picture of my sensor coordinates.
[image]

I have homogeneous vector, here are a few examples:

[image]

For the sensor coordinates I want to map Gaussian Noise to each point to simulate the sensor noise in a real case.

Right now I just map a random real to each coordinate but I want to test my calibration in a realisitc case.

Map[{RandomReal[{-0.005, 0.005}], RandomReal[{-0.005, 0.005}],
0} + # &, Quadrat];

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the data that you have and the code that you use to manipulate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `pts` with your points (shown in red). I have retained the third coordinate as `1`:

```
pts = Table[{i, j, 1}, {i, 3.0, 6.0, 0.7}, {j, 5.0, 6.0, 0.3}];
p1 = ListPlot[pts[[All, All, 1 ;; 2]], PlotStyle -> Red, 
   ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> {{2.8, 6}, {4.7, 6.2}}];
```

Evaluate the following repeatedly to see the jittered points (in blue). Change sd as required:

```
sd = 0.05;
ptsJittered = 
  Map[{RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, sd]], 
      RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, sd]], 0} + # &, pts, {2}];
p2 = ListPlot[ptsJittered[[All, All, 1 ;; 2]], PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> {{2.8, 6}, {4.7, 6.2}}];

Dynamic[Show[p1, p2]]
```

[image]

Please provide feedback when it is convenient.

Comment: Very nice to have you back at the forum and thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, you have coordinate pair `{x,y}`, then you can generate the pair with  random shifts `{x,y}+RandomInteger[{-l,l},2]`, where the `l` is a needed amplitude of the shift.

Or you can use the `RandomReal` if you want the non-integer shift values